# Error : property does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I am a newbie in coding world and learning angular 4. In my application,
I have 3 classes `MyGlobalObject.ts`, `globalservice.service.ts` and `history.ts`.

I am trying to fetch the data from a JSON file (API) having the values in `history.ts`, but in `globalservice` class, I am getting an error saying property `startdateandtime` does not exist on type `History[]`.

But the property do exist in the history.ts as shown in the above images having code.

`myglobalobject.ts:`

[image: CodeScreenshot#1]

[image: CodeScreenshot#2]

---

`History.ts:`

[image: CodeScreenshot#3]

---

`globalservice.service.ts:`

[image: CodeScreenshot#4]

Comment: Add image description.

Comment: **First: Please, copy-paste the code in code blocks as text.** Second: it, indeed, exists, but your code editor does not 'recognize' it because it cannot find an interface for it. During development this can be ignored, but it will probably fail to build during `ng build --prod`.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the type you have assigned to the variables is different than the data you are trying to put into it.

In your file, either declare type as **any**. or know the type of data you are going to put into the variable

example:

```
slno:  any;
```